# random entry sampling, restricting by fraction of a second

Tags: python, pandas

I have time stamped labeled data with non-regular number of entries per regular time period. Ie, sometimes I can have 25 entries in a second and others I can have 100 in a second (it's financial data).

To create a new database, I want to pick just one at random of the entries I have within a defined time section, say the first half of a second and the second half of a second to reduce the size of the dataset and also create uniformity within entries. How do I do this in pandas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best but I think it works: `resample` your DataFrame/Series by the division of a second you want, then pick a random row out of each bin (or put `NaN` if there is no data):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#making fake date, randomly picked times in a minute at 100ms frequency
dr = pd.date_range('01-01-2020 9:00:00', '01-01-2020 9:01:00', freq='100ms')
dates = sorted(np.random.choice(dr, size=100))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates,data=np.random.random(size=(100,2)),columns=['Values','Values2'])

#resample
resampled = df.resample('500ms')

#iterate over resampled, and pick a random row (if there, else np.nan)
output = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for time,frame in resampled:
    if not frame.empty:
        random_index = np.random.choice(range(len(frame.index)))
        output.loc[time] = list(frame.iloc[random_index])
    else:
        output.loc[time] = np.nan
```

Input:

```
#df.head(10)
                           Values   Values2
2020-01-01 09:00:00.100  0.190373  0.831841
2020-01-01 09:00:00.200  0.218069  0.586812
2020-01-01 09:00:00.500  0.611154  0.603198
2020-01-01 09:00:00.900  0.076038  0.061462
2020-01-01 09:00:00.900  0.519908  0.259880
2020-01-01 09:00:00.900  0.652016  0.925601
2020-01-01 09:00:01.000  0.256711  0.586374
2020-01-01 09:00:01.300  0.939387  0.409488
2020-01-01 09:00:01.400  0.075527  0.691568
2020-01-01 09:00:01.400  0.283443  0.490719
```

Output:

```
#output.head(3)
                           Values   Values2
2020-01-01 09:00:00.000  0.190373  0.831841
2020-01-01 09:00:00.500  0.652016  0.925601
2020-01-01 09:00:01.000  0.256711  0.586374
```